# Origin of the Batmobile's flame exhaust?

Tags: dc, batman, vehicles

It seems that, with the possible exception of some of the animated films, virtually every cinematic version of the Batmobile has a port on the back that shoots flames:

The 1966 Adam West film and television series had it. The Michael Keaton film and its sequels had it. The Christopher Nolan films had it (I think explained that the vehicle was intended for bridging rivers). The Ben Affleck film had it. And according to the [new trailer](https://youtu.be/ewDSeyWve8M?t=106), the Robert Pattinson film will have it.

So, where did the idea that the batmobile has a flame exhaust on the back come from? Was it already part of Batman lore by the mid '60s? Did it appear in the comics (particularly before 1966)? Or are all of these films paying homage to the 1966 version?

Comment: The batmobile in the classic TV serials certainly didn't have any fancy exhausts. They were basically stock models with the occasional fancy touch like video-chat

Comment: On the television show, it always looked to me like its was supposed to resemble a rocket.

Comment: @Buzz that's what I've always thought, a rocket to help them accelerate quicker

Comment: @SpacePhoenix - I always assumed that it was a jet afterburner. To give them extra oomph.

Comment: I think it was first in the tv series as it was part of the atomic turbine engine.  There is a website on the batmobile http://www.batmobilehistory.com/index.php which implies that was a new feature  - but short of exhaustively looking at every pre tv series comic it would be hard to prove none had jets unless there is an obvious example of something prior to the tv show. A Bat historian I'm sure is out there might have a good sense of when batman became a super scientist with state of the art technology vs mere costumed detective.

Comment: [There was a real world program to build turbine engine cars in the 1960s.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrysler_Turbine_Car)  Popular talk at the time [claimed the turbine car exhaust was "hot enough to melt the bumper off the car behind it."](https://www.roadandtrack.com/car-culture/a19598376/turbine-exhaust-will-not-melt-you/)  The Batmobile from the 1960s TV show was playing with that myth.  Listen to it.  The Batmobile in that series *whines.*  It has a turbine engine.

Comment: I don't have proof of that, so just a comment.

Comment: I think that that's a reasonable answer.

Comment: Just as an aside, the DC animated films (specifically those of the New 52 continuity that ended with "Justice League Dark: Apokolips War") also have the flame exhaust in the Batmobile.

Comment: @JRE They even tried it in [racing cars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotus_56) at the time. Alas (that's my inner Calvin lamenting), no flame exhaust.

Comment: @JRE Getting off topic here, but there is a quote from Jay Leno about his [MTT Turbine Superbike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MTT_Turbine_Superbike) melting the bumper of a car behind him.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batmobile#DC_Universe - if anyone has access to copy or scan Detective Comics #27, #30, #31, #48, and Batman #5 I think there will be an answer there.

Comment: @Skooba - Batman #5 doesn't have the flame exhaust and nor do any of the other comics you've mentioned.

Comment: @Valorum whelp, was worth a shot. not the first or last time wikipedia will lead someone astray.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 1966 Batmobile was the first version to include an exhaust port and was a trend setter as nearly every version of the [BatMobile](https://www.hotcars.com/evolution-of-the-batmobile-in-film-and-on-tv/) (live-action or animated) has featured it since.

The 1966 Batmobile was built off of a 1954 Future concept car, which needs a lot of work. After modifications one of the included features was a turbine exhaust port.

> The "rocket exhaust" was made functional via a tank filled with either gasoline or kerosene which was pumped out the exhaust port and ignited electrically. - [Wikipedia - Batmobile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batmobile#Exhibition)

Previous versions of the Batmobile were as basic as a normal red car (Detective Comics #27) to the fancy convertibles that served as the BatMobile and Bruce Wayne's personal car.

Why did the 1966 BatMobile have a jet exhaust? It is easy to assume they took inspiration from the real life 1963 Chrysler Turbine Car, which used a jet engine and had rear exhaust ports. The car itself was limited and not popular.

[image]

Comment: Might want to distinguish jet exhaust port. Robinson’s 1941 batmobile redesign had an exhaust port, just not a flame-exhaust. In fact, Batman’s first car — Bruce Wayne’s proto-batobile town car had an exhaust port.

Comment: In the 60's TV show there was always a lot of dialog of "turbines to speed" etc when first starting the Batmobile